# Xamarin XCT TabView - can the heading be setup to scroll/swipe into view more headers than fit horizontally?

Tags: xamarin.forms, tabview, xamarin-community-toolkit

Just trying out the TabView from the Xamarin Community Toolkit.
Is it possible to configure it so that tab headers scroll/swipe horizontally into view rather than having to shrink them into the available horizontal space?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

EDIT: As an example 20 tabs: Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4 ... | Tab 20. Many tabs and Tab 20 are hidden at first since they can't fit in the horizontal space. I would like the user to be able scroll through them to scroll it into view to select say Tab 20.

Comment: It's very difficult to understand what you mean. Could you please share a screenshot/diagram with an explanation? Are u basically asking if it possible to replicate Android's native TabbedPage behavior using XCT's TabView?

Comment: I'm not sure about android's native.   Imagine a set of tabs that don't fit horizontally in the space provided. I'm asking if rather than making them smaller, I'm able to scroll/swipe left and right to see the ones not shown. Once I scroll a hidden tab into view, I can now select that tab.      As an example: Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4  ... but Tab 4 is hidden at first and I need to scroll it into view to select it.

Comment: `Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3 | Tab 4 ... but Tab 4 is hidden at first`  I created a simple demo and copied the sample code from above link you set,  but the tab 4 is displayed not hidden . In addition,I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Exactly @JessieZhang-MSFT it's *NOT* hidden... I want TabView configured to scroll MANY tabs not try to fit them into the available space. Imagine 20 tabs ... you need to be able to 1) scroll through them or 2) display on multiple header lines... I would like to have them scrolled through.

Comment: Do you want to hide the middle tabs?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT No ... I want all tabs visible, but since there isn't enough horizontal space to show them I want user to be able to scroll headers into view.

Comment: `I want user to be able to scroll headers into view`   What do you mean  words `scroll headers into view` ?   What's the `headers `? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I'm calling Tabs Text "headers" to distinguish from the "content" you see when you click/select a Tab/Header.  So in my example the Headers are the text "Tab 1", "Tab 2" etc. Imagine 20 Tabs, w/o very small Header text or rows of Headers. I would like the user to be able to scroll through the Tabs/headers in a single before selecting one.

Comment: Currently,we can scroll from one page to another page. I'm really not sure what kind of functionality you want to implement.

Comment: Yes, you're talking the tab content. I'm talking the actual tabs on top.

Comment: Do you want to scroll the actual tabs not the tab contents ?

Comment: yes, scroll the "actual tabs"   No worries, I'm using another tool.

Comment: Have you found the solution? Could you please share it here so that it will help others who have similar problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I was not able to get the TabView configured to do that. I am using a CollectionView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... just set a width for the tabViewItem to what you want... and they will be scrollable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Calderon I think you are talking about being able to scroll the Content, read the comments that's not the question. I have solved my issue using CollectionView, but thanks.